# opencv - how to save Mat image in filestorage

Tags: opencv

I want to save a floating point one-channel image and I don't want to convert it. So I decided to use filestorage class to save it but I couldn't quite get how to do it from the documentation. And what I tried didn't work. Can anybody help me with this?

```
// Write:
FileStorage fs("img.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
Mat img;
fs << img;

// Read:
FileStorage fs("img.xml", FileStorage::READ);
Mat img;
fs >> img;
```

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Writing to file

```
cv::FileStorage storage("test.yml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
storage << "img" << img;
storage.release();
```

Reading from file

```
cv::FileStorage storage("test.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
storage["img"] >> img;
storage.release();
```

Comment: @ManuelIgnacioLópezQuintero I need to write a video stream which is made up of CV_16UC1 images. Can this method be used?

Comment: You could write multiple Mat objects to a single file.

Comment: If the original mat variable name is not known when reading from file, `storage.getFirstTopLevelNode() >> img` will also work