# Opencv: read data from file to a matrix, when saved as raw using operator <<

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

With OpenCv, it is very easy to save data from a `cv::Mat` to a raw text file:

```
cv::Mat m( 10, 10,CV_8UC1 );
// ... fill with values
std::ofstream f( "mydata.txt" );
f << m;
```

This produces a simple layout, say for int's:

```
[1, 2, 3, .... ;
 4, 5, 6, .... ;
 ...
 7, 8, 9, ... ]
```

My question is: when saved that way, **how do you read back** the data (assuming you know the size and type of matrix).
This would be great:

```
cv::Mat m( 10, 10,CV_8UC1 );
std::ifstream f( "mydata.txt" );
f >> m;
```

but unfortunatly it does not compile. Do I really have to go through `getline()` and all the associated checking, tokenizing,... to do that ? (I mean, besides using YAML/XML [as described here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html)). Does Opencv provide some simpler syntax ?

And if you like template error messages, here are they:

```
error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_istream<char>&&’
infile >> mymat;
          ^
error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = cv::Mat]’
 operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __is, _Tp& __x)
```

Comment: any reason you can't use YAML files? What you want sounds almost exactly like what YAML would provide (a YAML file is effectively just a text file with the matrix dimensions and type)

Comment: @alrikai not really, it's just that I expected a "reverse" operator, similar and as simple as the << operator, but to read data.  I'll probably end-up using YAML, these [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115046) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547001) I just found will help.

Answer (score 2):

1.You can proceed like here in this [link1](http://answers.opencv.org/question/42770/how-to-read-matrix-from-text-file-to-mat-in-opencv/) , he tried to separate between his Mat's cols , check it with your self maybe your problem is how to stock your data not how to read it!

2.Or try to use "File storage" and save your file as XML/YML as proposed here in this [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200844/how-to-read-the-text-file-and-create-mat-object-in-c)

Comment: Thanks. 1 - `your problem is how to stock your data`: Nope, what I want is reading data as simply as I write it in the file: `f << m;` 2 - Yes, I know that, I'd just wanted to see if there was a way to avoid it.